# Reading data from embedded controller using COM port using java

Tags: java

We are receiving data from controller using terminal software and as well as also java program. We get proper output from terminal software but the java program returns a different output. Input data is in ASCII and we convert it to HEX, terminal application show proper data but java program does not show proper data.

Terminal data is

[image: terminal img]

and java program data is
[image: Java img]

Problem in that data mismatch in conversion ASCII TO HEX 
Terminal data is

> --- D2 0F 24 28 07 0D 3C 7C 05 23 00 0A 05 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 CC 0F 24 28 07 0D 3C 7C 05 23 00 0A 05 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3C DD
>   19 19 19 19 19 00 00 1C 00 1D 19 19 18 1A 00 62 10 00 00 00 7A CC and

java Program data is

> ----- FFFD F 24 28 7 D 3C 7C 5 23 0 A 5 1 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 42 FFFD F 24 28 7 D 3C 7C 5 23 0 A 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3C FFFD 1A
>   19 1A 1A 1A 0 0 A 0 A 19 1A 19 1E 0 62 10 0 0 0 5F FFFD

D2 is Showing in java FFFD 
CC is also showing FFFD 
we just want same output like Terminal

```java
import java.io.*; // IOException
import java.util.*; // Scanner
import jssc.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Emiliarge
 */
public class ComPortSendReceive1 {

    private static SerialPort serialPort;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();

        if (portNames.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("There are no serial-ports :( You can use an emulator, such ad VSPE, to create a virtual serial port.");
            System.out.println("Press Enter to exit...");
            try {
                System.in.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }

        // Ð²Ñ‹Ð±Ð¾Ñ€ Ð¿Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‚Ð°
        System.out.println("Available com-ports:");
        for (int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
            System.out.println(portNames[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Type port name, which you want to use, and press Enter...");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String portName = in.next();

        // writing to port
        serialPort = new SerialPort(portName);
        try {
            // opening port
            serialPort.openPort();

            serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                                 SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                                 SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                                 SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | 
                                          SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);

            serialPort.addEventListener(new PortReader(), SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
            // writing string to port
            serialPort.writeString("Hurrah!!!");

            System.out.println("String wrote to port, waiting for response..");
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in writing data to port: " + ex);
        }
    }

    // receiving response from port
    private static class PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

        @Override
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
                try {
                    // Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑƒÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¾Ñ‚Ð²ÐµÑ‚Ð° Ð¾Ñ‚ Ð¿Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‚Ð°
                    String receivedData = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());


                    for (char ch : receivedData.toCharArray()) {
                            System.out.format("%H ", ch);

                        } // prints "31 32 2E 30 31 33 "

                }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error in receiving response from port: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of those two images into the question. They can be formatted similar to code.

Comment: erminal data is --- D2 0F 24 28 07 0D 3C 7C 05 23 00 0A 05 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 CC 0F 24 28 07 0D 3C 7C 05 23 00 0A 05 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3C DD 19 19 19 19 19 00 00 1C 00 1D 19 19 18 1A 00 62 10 00 00 00 7A CC and java Program data is ----- FFFD F 24 28 7 D 3C 7C 5 23 0 A 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 42 FFFD F 24 28 7 D 3C 7C 5 23 0 A 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3C FFFD 1A 19 1A 1A 1A 0 0 A 0 A 19 1A 19 1E 0 62 10 0 0 0 5F FFFD

D2 is Showing in java FFFD CC is also showing FFFD we just want same output like Terminal

Comment: Please edit them into the question. When somebody comes back in a few years and searches the question, they may not read the xomments.

Comment: these contain already added in the question.

Comment: For some of it, try printing with %2H rather than just H. That should get you the leading zeros.

Comment: You might also try slowing down the baud rate and experimenting with parity. On both sides, of course.

Comment: %2H is not working  its show now--- FFFD  F 24 28  7  D 3C 7C  5 23  0  A  5  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 42 FFFD  F 24 28  7  D 3C 7C  5 23  0  A  5  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 3C FFFD

Comment: You'll have to look up the printing specification yourself, then. I won't be on my Java computer for hours. I'm on a tablet now. I'll check it when I have the chance. You might try %2.0h, but that's off the top of my head

Comment: hello sir i just tried %2.0h but data is not showing over there on console

Comment: actually we are getting data from controller .. which is chaina made UART protocol

Comment: Please try %02X for the format specification. For some reason leading zeros with the h specification caused an error.

Comment: Exception in thread "EventThread com3" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: x != java.lang.Character
B� at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
 at jssc_com_port.ComPortSendReceive1$PortReader.serialEvent(ComPortSendReceive1.java:92)

Comment: The error seems to be that one of the bytes does not describe a Java character. It looks to be in SerialPort.readString() or the following line in toByteArray(), but I think it's the former.

Comment: now how we can solve these issue ?

Comment: What type of data are you really sending? Are you sending text, or are you sending raw bytes of data?

Comment: Data is sending through microcontroller every .5sec ,data is analog and digital.on rs485port

Comment: There are a couple things you can do. The first one is to not convert it to character data. Use a method that reads byte[]. Then convert the various bytes to their proper form. And your 485 port is *not* transporting analog date, but rather analog data that has been translated to digital form. I've built robots and done this. If the data is still noisy, you may need to use a protocol to transport it more reliably. Checksums, redundency, that sort of thing.

Comment: Jssc has a readBytes() method (one with a length and timeout and the other with just a timeout). Both return a byte[].

Comment: thank you so much sir ... now is working correctly

Comment: byte[] receivedData = serialPort.readBytes(event.getEventValue());
for (byte b : receivedData) {
                        String st = String.format("%02X", b);
                        System.out.print(st+" ");
                    }